# how to print list of sub-folders and number files in each sub-folder side by side, in the current directory?

Tags: file, command-line

I am at the directory: 
`/home/john/my_test_files/`
and under the directory there are 100 folders:

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
...
folder100
```

what command would I use to print the list of folders and the each one's file count side by side. Something like this:

```
folder1     25
folder2     78
folder3     34
...
folder100   88
```

where `folder1` has 25 files in it, `folder2` has 78 files in it, etc

I'm sure this is something basic but I couldn't find a good answer...

Comment: Try this: ```for x in *; do [[ -d "$x" ]] && echo -n "$x " && (ls "$x" | wc -l); done```

Comment: I just removed the "linux" tag, read it's documentation for further info. In its stead, you could add the tag with the shell that you're using.

Comment: @accdias if you put the comment as an answer post, I'll upvote and accept the answer. it should work for your points :)

Comment: @IonutTicus if you put the comment as an answer post, I'll upvote . it should work for your points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
du --inodes --max-depth=1 /home/john/my_test_files/
```

It will also include the inode for the directories themselves but it's quick and easy to remember.

Answer (score 0):

as @accdias pointed:

`for x in *; do [[ -d "$x" ]] && echo -n "$x " && (ls "$x" | wc -l); done`

another method is:

`find . -mindepth 1 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} sh -c 'printf "%4d : %s\n" "$(find {} -type f | wc -l)" "{}"'`